# 301 Redirect Entire Domain Order of Commands Issue

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, dns

**I have yet another Domain 301 Redirect Question.**

The .htaccess file is below.  When I perform the full domain redirect, should the *domain* redirect fall before or after the redirects I currently have on the website due to some poor planning.

Long story short, I had a weebly site, I exported that and rebuilt it from scratch (it was a nightmare).  Now I am just switching to a more SEO friendly domain name.  When I moved it out, I also decided to change the URLs of many of the pages, so I initially had a lot of 404s and pages not being indexed.

**.htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 messagebrd.pl index.html index.htm

ErrorDocument 403 /403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

Header append Vary User-Agent

RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-old.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example-old.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^2/(.*)
RewriteRule /index.html [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1/(.*)
RewriteRule /index.html [R=301,L]


RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example-new.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example-new.com/$1 [L,R=301]}
```

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to this?  Just want to make sure it's done correctly the first time.  Also, my sites are indexing two different pages for root and /index.html.  Whats the best way to resolve this, do I need to add `directory index /` as well to the top of my htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

> should the domain redirect fall before or after the redirects I currently have

The "full domain redirect", and by that I assume you mean the redirect from `example-old.com` to `example-new.com`, should be at the top of your redirects.

I assume `example-old.com` and `example-new.com` currently resolve to the same site - the new site. In which case you can combine your domain and `www` canonical redirects. For example, replace the following:

> `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-old.com`
>       `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example-old.com/$1 [R=301,L]`
>
> `RewriteBase /`
>       `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example-new.com$ [NC]`
>       `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example-new.com/$1 [L,R=301]}`

With this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example-new.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example-new.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should go at the top of your mod_rewrite directives, immediately after the `RewriteEngine On` directive. This basically says, if the requested host is *not* `www.example-new.com` then redirect to `www.example-new.com`. So, this will catch `example-old.com`, `www.example-old.com` and `example-new.com` and anything else that isn't `www.example-new.com`!

Incidentally, you had an erroneous `}` (curly brace) at the end of the `RewriteRule` and the `RewriteBase` directive is not required here.

---

> `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^2/(.*)`
>       `RewriteRule /index.html [R=301,L]`
>
> `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1/(.*)`
>       `RewriteRule /index.html [R=301,L]`

These two rules are invalid and don't actually do anything - or at least they don't do what they should be doing! The *substitution* (target URL) is missing from both the `RewriteRule` directives. But the `RewriteCond` directives also don't make sense and will never match anyway.

---

> Also, my sites are indexing two different pages for root and `/index.html`.

Presumably you don't want the `/index.html` indexed and are referencing only `/` in your URLs? You can try adding the following redirect following the redirect above to help resolve this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This obviously assumes that `index.html` is your only `DirectoryIndex` (the file that Apache tries to return when you request a directory).

> `DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 messagebrd.pl index.html index.htm`

If you only have `index.html` index documents then you don't need to specify all the others that are not used. Incidentally, this list of files are in order to preference. Apache will first look for `index.php`, then `index.php3`, etc.

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN FOR REAL!  For one site I do only have one DirectoryIndex index.html

Comment: Should I not have the index.html _indexed_ and only have the root(/) index?

Comment: Should I not have the index.html **_indexed_** and only have the root(/) index?  It really surprises me that you need to need to redirect the index file or the search engines will see duplicates.  `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]`  Why did you use **reg** markup that rule and not the others (if thats the right term for it, where you indicate a \ before slashes or periods).

Comment: Well, generally people prefer users to see (and get indexed) `example.com/` and `example.com/directory/`, rather than `example.com/index.html` and `example.com/directory/index.html` respectively as it simply looks _cleaner_. If you always link to the bare directory (ie. don't include `index.html` in the URL) then it's unlikely that Google and other users will find the `index.html` URL and you don't necessarily need to redirect one to the other. However, they are technically different URLs, so if both are indexed (or linked to) then you ideally need to set a preference (ie. redirect).

Comment: Note that you can also set this "preference" with the `<link rel="canonical" ...` element. This will help Google index the correct URL (ie. with or without `index.html`), without having to redirect. Although users can still access the "wrong" URL.

Comment: "Why did you use reg markup" - The second parameter to the `RewriteRule` directive (`/$1` in the example you quoted and `http://www.example-new.com/$1` above) isn't actually a regular expression (regex), so no backslash escapes required there. In the `RewriteCond` directive above, the `=` operator in `!=www.example-new.com` actually makes it an ordinary string (a string comparison), not a regex, as it would otherwise be, so again, no backslash escapes required here.

Comment: So Say, for example, I have an older page seo.html that keeps getting indexed for some reason even though its been gone.  I have another url which is the starting seo-url and that is seo-2015.html.  should i use a redirect, a  CNAME or a rel-canonical

Comment: In that case you should use a redirect. For example, `RewriteRule ^seo\.html$ /seo-2015.html [R=301,L]` - since you need to _redirect_ users as well as search engines. (A `CNAME` DNS record does not apply here.)